# How To get Data Between Two Timestamp in Solaris

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I have log file from which I want to get the data between two timestamp but I dont want to involve dates. Since I am writing one script which can run daily that is why I am not considering dates.
My log files looks like ####<22-Sep-2016 8:54:56 o'clock PM EDT> Info......
and Every line start from here. 
For example I need data of Every 15 minutes at any time stamp and I want my script to run at every 15 minutes.

I have used these commands to print data between two time stamp...

```
sed '/13:29:28/,/13:35:02/p' mvwlp_s1_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log
```

And this command as well

```
sed -n '/####<date +"%d-%b-%y" 3:30:09 o'clock PM EDT>/p,/####<date +"%b %d,                                                                       %y" 3:20:09 o'clock PM EDT>/p' mvwlp_s1_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log
```

But Both of this is not working

Comment: `sed  -n '/^13:29:28/,/^13:35:02/p' mvwlp_s1_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log`

Comment: I have tried this and it is not working. @PS.

Comment: Need to know what is `not working` means ? is it displaying wrong output or syntax error or other ?

Comment: @PS. It is Not giving any output and not even any error message. :(

Comment: try `awk '/^13:29:28/,/^13:35:02/' mvwlp_s1_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log` this should work. If this does not work then visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns